# Disabling GIF animation in HTML

Tags: html, animation, gif, animated-gif

Is there any way, in HTML, to include an animated GIF in an <img> tag, but automatically tell the GIF to not animate?  I realize that the user can stop animation by pressing ESC or clicking Stop, but I want the GIFs not to animate at all.

I only want to do this on one specific page, and making separate non-animated versions of the (1500+) GIFs is not feasible.  I simply want the GIFs to not animate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stopping Gif Animation Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

Comment: Have look at this : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) This might solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Giffer](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/krasimir/gifffer/master/build/gifffer.min.js).

Just include the library in your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gifffer.min.js"></script>
```

Instead of setting src attribute on your image use data-gifffer.

```
<img data-gifffer="image.gif" />
```

At the end, call `Gifffer()` whenever you want. For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
    Gifffer();
}
```

If you don't want the GIF to move at all you can always edit the .js file to remove the play button.

Answer (score 1):

Not with plain HTML but using PHP with [imagecreatefromgif](http://mx.php.net/imagecreatefromgif) might help you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think calling window.stop() will be a good solution. This would need to be called for every image that is loaded to prevent it from running half way through and stopping. The best solution is to use a library such as GD to create images featuring just the first frame of the animated GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Use ImageMagik, and you can readily convert all 1500 images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.stop()` in javascript, which should be the equivalent of pressing ESC/clicking stop. However, I'm pretty sure it won't work in all browsers (i.e. IE).