# animated gif icon for button html

Tags: html, css

I am new to html.I need a `delete` button with `animated style`. I have used a `gif` image for `animation`. I want this image to be run when the user place the mouse over it. Currently, the gif image is running infinite.
How to make the image run when the user move the mouse over it. Help me with some solutions.
If you have any other transparent delete image, please provide, it can help me.

Here's the markup I tried:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <a>
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/1RGh8PpK/delete.gif"
           alt="Delete image" width="100" height="100" />
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set a static image for the default state and swap it with a gif on hover.

Comment: Thanks for the response. can i get any examples for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animating a gif on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473117/animating-a-gif-on-hover)

Comment: @Harun Yilmaz, the answer doesn't work.. it was an outdated one.

Comment: What do you mean by "outdated"? It is written in jQuery but you can convert it to pure JavaScript or CSS.

Answer (score 6):

Head on over [EZGIF](https://ezgif.com/crop) to **crop your gif** and make it an appropriate size for a button:

[image]

Use your computer to take a **static screenshot** of the gif (you'll have to time it right):

[image]

Use **HTML** to hold *both* the static and animated image elements:

```
<img class='static_trash' id = 'static_btn' src='https://collaboratescience.com/stack/googs/trash_static.png' alt='Delete image' width='100' height='100' />

<img class='live_trash' id = 'live_btn' src='https://i.postimg.cc/1RGh8PpK/delete.gif' alt='Delete image' width='100' height='100' />
```

Use **CSS** to set live_trash to "**display: none**"

```
. live_trash {
    "display" : "none"
}
```

Use **JavaScript** to change image source on hover:

**Vanilla JavaScript**:

```
let static_elem = document.getElementById("static_btn")
let live_elem = document.getElementById("live_btn")

static_elem.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {   
    event.target.style.display = "none";
    live_elem.style.display = "block"
})

static_elem.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {   
    event.target.style.display = "block";
    live_elem.style.display = "none"
})
```

**Result**:

[image]

You can play with crop sizing to get it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with JavaScript or CSS. All you need is a static frame from the gif.

#### JavaScript

You can utilize the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` mouse events to alter the `src` of the image.

```js
const states = {
  'default': "https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHTA.png",
  'hover': "https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwxRR.gif"
};

let img = document.querySelector('#hover-img');

img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  img.setAttribute('src', states.hover);
});
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  img.setAttribute('src', states.default);
});
```

```html
<a>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHTA.png" id="hover-img" alt="Delete image" width="100" height="100" />
</a>
```

#### CSS

Or, you can determine if the user if hovering over the element using the CSS pseudo-class [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover), but you will probably want to use a `<div>` or a `<span>` instead of a `<img>`.

```css
.hoverable {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: center url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHTA.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.hoverable:hover {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwxRR.gif');
}
```

```html
<a><span class="hoverable"></span></a>
```

#### JavaScript using data tags

Alternatively, you can associate the default and hover state with the element via `data-*` attributes.

You can utilize the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` mouse events to alter the `src` of the image.

```js
let img = document.querySelector('#hover-img');

img.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  img.setAttribute('src', e.target.getAttribute('data-hover-src'));
});
img.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
  img.setAttribute('src', e.target.getAttribute('data-default-src'));
});
```

```html
<a>
  <img id="hover-img" alt="Delete image" width="100" height="100"
    src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHTA.png"
    data-default-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJHTA.png"
    data-hover-src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwxRR.gif" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a {
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/1RGh8PpK/static-delete.png")
}
a:hover {
    background-image: url("https://i.postimg.cc/1RGh8PpK/delete.gif")   
}
```

Comment: rest of the css you need to add here

Comment: how to write it in tag <a>

Comment: above css  you need to write in css file or in style tag

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.