# Stop GIFs from Preloading

Tags: javascript, web

I am playing with a new website I created a few days ago.
The site contains lots and lots of gifs there is displayed on the frontpage. As of right now, a static .png thumbnail is showed and when hovered, it displays the gif instead.

This is pretty much what I want. However, as of now, the site preloads every single gif on the page, which takes a long time and a lot traffic is wasted. If there are 50 gifs on the frontpage and every gif is 2mb, that's 100mb traffic per user.
Isn't it possible to only load every png, then load the gif if it's hovered? I know it won't play smooth the first time, but I don't have a whole lot of web traffic on my web hotel.

Is this possible with either some PHP or good-old JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: How are you switching out the png with the gif? CSS? Javascript?

Comment: How are you doing the hovering change? With CSS?

Comment: PHP is server side, so it's not relevant. What you want is JavaScript, which runs on the client side. CSS might also work (with the :hover event), but I'm not sure if it will also preload the image (easy enough to check by testing it and watching the server logs).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the URL of the image with hover. In this case with jQuery

```
$('#my_image').hover(function(){
    $('#my_image').attr('src','my.gif');
});
```

Want to make it dynamic without having to set it per image? Add the HTML5 Data element:

```
<img src="my.png" data-gif="my.gif" />
```

And with JavaScript:

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).data('gif'));
});
```

Comment: Where would I add the jQuery and JavaScript to my page? Do I have to use the HTML5 Data element for all my <img> tags?

Comment: use the data element for all images you want to replace. The jQUery can be put anywhere, just don't forget to include jQuery on your site

Comment: ...or better don't use jQuery for simple tasks like that one, it's overhead.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rBT4RBbW Something like this or do I miss something? It just display the thumbnail, no gif when hovered

Comment: copy the second javascript i posted, not the first one ;)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HPk0CBNw How it looks now, but gif doesn't load on hover though

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4hSd/ Are you sure jQuery is implemented?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/38gWx1dp This is how my Testing site looks, nothing happens when I hover over my png thumbnail. I also tried to use src="scripts/jquery.js" in my body, didn't work either

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8090/discussion-between-ninjaboi21-and-topener)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the HTML that contains the GIFs to the DOM after page load, inserting it as a string or using AJAX.

Another viable solution is to use CSS sprites and eliminate all those images by combining them into a larger one.

Comment: How do you use AJAX to load an image?

Comment: You don't - you use AJAX to grab the HTML that contains the image references.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about it the wrong way. Browsers don't request images unless you include the images in your page. You shouldn't try to prevent included images from being loaded, you should simply not include the images in the first place.

Remove the image URL from your code. In whatever code you have that currently makes the hidden image visible, you can set the URL as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are the file names the same except for the extension? If so I would recommend this approach

[Stop a gif animation onload, on mouseover start the activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818003/stop-a-gif-animation-onload-on-mouseover-start-the-activation)

What you would do different is replace the `.png` with `.gif` this will load the gif on hover instead of at page load. Right now it sounds like you are loading both the .png and the .gif in a hidden div.

Edit:

Then on mouseout you would switch the source back to the `.png`.