# Gif wont animate on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I saw this post and I tried to replicate the code: [Stop a gif animation onload, on mouseover start the activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818003/stop-a-gif-animation-onload-on-mouseover-start-the-activation?answertab=votes#tab-top). I can't seem to get it to work though. My goal is to swap the image with a gif on hover. Does someone know why the image isn't swapping?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imgAnimate").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "images/portfolio/form.gif");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "images/portfolio/form.jpg");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns portfolio-pic animated slideInUp">
    <div data-content="Project 1" class="image">
      <a class="a-block" href="#">
        <img id="imgAnimate" src="images/portfolio/form.jpg">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a live link to my example: http://fosterinnovationculture.com/dcc/index.html

Comment: add jquery to your page

Comment: @anthony write answers as answers and not as edits. it is just confusing and you dont earn any credits ;)

Comment: I didn't know my edit would fix it, all I did was add jQuery :P  But yeah I understand, thanks.  I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @AnthonyAstige Your edit hasn't fixed it yet. Check out the link:  http://fosterinnovationculture.com/dcc/index.html

Comment: @marcos Test with a snippit, not an entire website which can introduce a lot of problems.  To see if the snippit works, real images still have to be put in (it looks like the swapping is working, but I can't tell without real images there if the animation swapping is).

Comment: I didn't see `.gif` variant of that image. When i tried to edit the source it didn't work load up on 2/3 attempts. I suggest you to catch the images first for a better rendering.

Comment: Also, i can see you have two versions of `jQuery` on that page, one is uncompressed _v2.2_ and other is minified _v3.0_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what your page is saying jQuery is undefined. So either you are trying to execute jquery code before jquery is executed.

I executed this code on your site just to testing things out and it seems to be working

```js
function mousein () {
  $(this).attr("src", "images/portfolio/form.gif");
  console.log('hello')
}

function mouseout () {
  $(this).attr("src", "images/portfolio/form.jpg");
}

console.log($('#imgAnimate').hover(mousein, mouseout));
```

I did notice though that because of some styling issues the hover was never actually hitting the img it was actually hitting the `.image:after` css psuedo selector so you need to reorganize your html or change the way you select the element you want to switch the src of.

just to test in your html move the image outside of 
`<div class="image">image</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes its correct as told by @madalin ivascu, you need to add jquery at header and it will work.

Like this,

**HTML**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#imgAnimate").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "banana.gif");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).attr("src", "banana.png");
    });
});
</script>
</head>


<body>
    /* include your html part here */
    <a class="a-block" href="#">
        <img id="imgAnimate" src="banana.png" alt="">
    </a>

</body>
```

Comment: I added the JQuery reference to the header but it's still not working. Here is the updated example:  (http://fosterinnovationculture.com/dcc/index.html)

Comment: @marcos check this fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/azt2yhu6/1/ its working

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Instead of using `hover`, try that using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".row").find('img').mouseenter(function(){
    if($("#imgAnimate").attr('src','form.jpg')){
        $("#imgAnimate").attr('src','form.gif');
    }
    $(this).mouseleave(function(){
        if($("#imgAnimate").attr('src','form.gif')){
        $("#imgAnimate").attr('src','form.jpg');
    }
    });
  });
});
```