# Display GIF in html 5

Tags: html, gif

Is there a way to display a gif in HTML 5?
I've tried this code, and it doesn't work (images work though)

```html
<img src="loading.gif">
```

I've spent hours trying to find out how to do this, thanks!

Comment: That should work, assuming the image is available. There's nothing special about GIF images. We're not going to be able to help without more information. Console errors?

Comment: sounds like an incomplete path.

Comment: That must work. It seems you have picked the wrong url.

Comment: may this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38309480/how-to-animate-gifs-in-html-document bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference to your image is incomplete since your code itself is fine.

Your code reads as: the image is located at `http://example.com/loading.gif`.

You need to either put the complete url path (`https://media.giphy.com/media/jUwpNzg9IcyrK/giphy.gif` or use ellipses (`../media/giphy.gif`) to go back a directory.

```html
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/jUwpNzg9IcyrK/giphy.gif">
```

Comment: Ok thank you, for some reason the URL I had tried was faulty-even though I copied the link using the "copy link button" on giphy. Wasn't sure if there was an error in my code

Comment: just make sure the link is a valid image :)