# How to stop a GIF image from playing and only show the first frame in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, gif, animated-gif

I'm trying to make a GIF only plays when hovering, in Vuejs. The GIF I'm using is a dynamically fetched GIF from an API. The API returns the GIF URL. How to make it stop animating and only show the first frame?

N.B without changing the src with a static image (because there's no static image in the API i'm using).

I tried CSS animation and it didn't work.

Comment: See this question: [Stop a gif animation onload, on mouseover start the activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818003/stop-a-gif-animation-onload-on-mouseover-start-the-activation). There is an [answer using a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69567589/10441671) to show the gif's first frame and play the gif on mouseover, for example