# Prevent GIF files from reloading when another component uses it in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, gif

I have two components, let's say `componentA` and `componentB`. Both component import a `.gif` file, let's say `image.gif`. `image.gif` does not loop, so it should be played once only if it's not updated.

Initially `componentA` renders `image.gif` but not `componentB`. So the `image.gif` inside `componentA` is played once. When I render `image.gif` inside `componentB`, `image.gif` inside componentA is played again, which is not wanted.

Can it be done? Thanks!

Edit: Some simple codes for reproducing:

`Component A`
    import image as './image.gif'

```
export default class componentA extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={image} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`Component B`
    import image as './image.gif'

```
export default class componentA extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.show ? <img src={image} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`App`

```
import componentA from './componentA.react'
import componentB from './componentB.react'

export default class App extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            show: false,
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // ...or some moment when the App thinks componentB should update
        this.setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                show: true,
            });
        }, 4000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <componentA />
            <componentB show={this.state.show} />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you, please, provide some code so we can help you ? How are componentA and B composed ?

Comment: Added some samples

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use a bit more complex (and more flexible) structure:
use static and animated gifs and swap them with javascript.

Like was suggested in similar cases:

[Stop a gif animation onload, on mouseover start the activation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818003/stop-a-gif-animation-onload-on-mouseover-start-the-activation)

[JavaScript to control image animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286905/javascript-to-control-image-animation)

Comment: But if I have different ending times for different gifs (and loading them dynamically), I will have to record the ending time of each gif, which may even be impossible for me.

Answer (score 0):

As `this.setState` runs the `this.render` method, your 2 components are rerendered.

You can try the following :

Component A :

```
export default class componentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <img src={image} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Component B :

```
export default class componentB extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super(props)
        this.state = { show: false }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                show: true,
            });
        }, 4000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.show ? <img src={image} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

App :

```
import componentA from './componentA.react'
import componentB from './componentB.react'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        // Carefull here, you have to return a single `node` in the render method
        return (
            <div>
                <componentA />
                <componentB />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you, some points:

1. componentA and componentB is actually extending React.PureComponent, so they won't re-render unless the props has changed (so componentA should never re-render)

2. The timeout should be controlled by Grid, as componentB should never know when the gif should be loaded.

Apologies for mistakes.

Comment: Oh alright, my knowledge of PureComponent is equal to null ! I'll give it a look though !

Comment: Looks like it will render with PureComponent anyway as I read in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) the following:

If your React component’s render() function renders the same result given the same props and state, you can use React.PureComponent for a performance boost in some cases.

As your state changes, I think it actually rerenders everything ! That's why I moved the state in ComponentB to try to solve your issue !

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate
if the state does not change, react PureComponent does not re-render.

Comment: And what do you this this.setState does ? Put a consol.log('renders'); in your render method and you'll see.

Comment: I tried to put a console.log('render') in each of the component. It logs three times in total, two for the initial render of each component, and the third when componentB updates.