# Is it possible to play a GIF backwards via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, gif

I have a back and forth animation GIF in a web page.

Is it possible in any ways (presumably javascript) to display a GIF containing only half of the animation and have the same file played backwards ? My goal is to save space.

It is still fine if the solution is iOS only. No jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2385203/139010

Comment: Thanks and sorry I didn't find it.

Comment: It was right in the sidebar `:)` →

Comment: So, the answer from the link is yes, by converting the gif to a byte stream and manually manipulating it. The author of that library seems to really understand the composition of gif images.

Comment: Note that this library doesn't work very well with transparent GIF.