# start gif animation on visible slide - Flexslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

I am building tutorial using Flexslider (woo themes). There are 4 slides and each slide is having an animated gif file. All the slides play their animation at the same time even the hidden ones.

The question is how can I set the slides to play the gif animation only when they are visible?

```html
<div class="flexslider">
 <ul class="slides">
    <li> Slide 1 <img src"img/animatedgif1.gif" /></li>
    <li> Slide 2 <img src"img/animatedgif2.gif" /> </li>
    <li> Slide 3 <img src"img/animatedgif3.gif" /></li>
    <li> Slide 4 <img src"img/animatedgif4.gif" /></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527534/gif-slider-in-flexslider-how-to-begin-the-gif-only-when-on-slider