# How to edit frames/second for a gif image using HTML5 tag

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a loading image (gif) that will be displayed as a modal after window.load
I download it, but it's too fast!

> How to edit the speed of it, is there something in javascript or HTML5 tag that can change the amount of frames per second?

the attached Image is below:
[the gif image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biGPo.gif)

Comment: I don't think there is. You can edit the frames per second of the gif in a good image editor. You can also convert in another format, use the video tag, and from there you have a lot more control with the speed and such

Comment: Interesting links in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript … Some libraries are mentioned, x-gif in particular has a 'speed' attribute which seems like exactly what you need.

Comment: It's not possible because your trying to manipulate something that cannot be manipulated by HTML5. However it can be manipulated using a image editing package. I'm assuming your not using sprites as you can use CSS3 to create the loading image from a GIF sprite file.

Comment: Thank you everyone. .. I just want to know that not only for this loading gif ... I'm asking in general ... thank you at all

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lib like this one https://yahoo.github.io/gifshot/ as you mentioned you want for future, this allows for most gif options, and also using only js.

There is a demo for it also here http://www.elgom3a.com/post/the-fastest-online-video-to-gif-converter