# how to play specific parts of a gif depending on user's actions

Tags: javascript, html, css, animated-gif

Let's say i have a gif image of a cat, which for 3 seconds shows the cat walking, and after that the cat jumps. I want to implement the following:

- In a specific container div, the cat gif (which has a transparent background) should walk freely and follow the cursor. This means that only the part from 0 - 3 seconds should be played, and then the gif should be restarted, making it seem like a perfect loop.
- When the user clicks, the cat gif should jump, so the part after 3 seconds should be played, and then the cat should walk again.

I have no idea how to tangle with the frames of the gif. The only thing i have so far is the "follow" part.

```
<body>
    <div onmousemove="follow(event)" id="container">
        <img id="cat" src="cat.gif">
    </div>
    <script>
        function follow(event) {
            var cat = document.getElementById("cat");

            cat.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
            cat.style.top = event.pageY + 'px';

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Is what i am asking possible? Do i need 2 seperate gifs, one for the jump and one for the walk, or will one suffice? Is there some module i can use to handle the gif part?

Comment: Perhaps the starting point is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript

Comment: I'll check this out, though i'll definitely need some example usage sooner or later...