# Change background at specific GIF frame

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, web

I am looking for an advice to do some “animation” on my home page on a WordPress website,
I have a gif playing once on my home page,
I would like to change the background color, only at a specific frame of the gif. When the gif hit its 80 frame, the background should switch from white to black.
Can it be done with javascript ?
Could you direct me on how to do that ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Why not use a video instead? They are usually smaller than equivalent animated GIFs, plus the HTML video element gives you far more control.

Comment: [Check this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

A gif with 80 frames or more is not really good for your website. I strongly recommend using a plugin like [Slider Revolution](https://revolution.themepunch.com/) to create animations or use other methods like [Animate It!](https://wordpress.org/plugins/animate-it/) 
A video would be another possible option too. You can convert your gif into video with the help of some online tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
I can use a video, sure, it's even better for me, but how can I change the background color at a specific time of this video ? 
I am gonna check your suggestions, any more help would be appreciate,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can create your gif in Photoshop (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ot5GwpQPjF0) and change the color of background for specific layer or use more advanced tools like AfterEffects. If you open a gif in Photoshop you will have multiple layers. Select the layer you want to change the background color and edit it using Photoshop itself.