# Gif inside button (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css, button, gif

I am searching for a way to display/play a gif inside of a button.
The button should have a gif inside it, that starts playing on hover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to use CSS

```
<style>
.button {
background: url('gifname.gif');
border: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
<button class="button">
```

I hope that solves your problem

Comment: Tried it, but didnt get it to work :/
Do you have a jsbin or codepen link?