# Javascript control GIF speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

I'm making chrome extension that shows GIF faster than original and....

I'm looking for something to control the speed of GIF

[Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript)

I've seen this questions but X-gif is not working because of HTML import problem and SuperGif doesn't seems to support speed control...

Is there any way to control GIF speed?

Comment: There's another answer in the linked duplicate that should still work to convert the GIF in question to a spritesheet, and use CSS to animate through each frame.

Comment: check http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript)

Comment: @A Paul
I'm making the extension that fetch the websites Gif and make it faster in that website...
And using CSS sprite doesn't seems to fit this...Is there some tools that convert GIF to Sprite in Javascript? I couldn't find it..