# Is there any way to pick a random frame as the starting point of a gif?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a bat gif that I have on html5 webgame.

I want to put many of them next to each other but since the gifs start playing at the same time, it doesn't look great.

I want to randomly offset each gif but there doesn't seem to be any solutions out there...

From a quick google, i saw libgif: https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js, but it hasnt been maintained in over 6 years and I don't see the option im looking for.

Anyone have experience with this?

If there are no ways around this, then I guess ill manually draw up different variations

Comment: Maybe look at some of the answers on [Can you control GIF animation with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385203/can-you-control-gif-animation-with-javascript). If those don't work, one hacky way might be to display some of the gifs early and style them invisible.

Comment: that post is where i found the libgif library. That does seem very hacky since to achieve the effect im looking for, i would then need to use setTimeouts as my way of creating the offset... Ill try it out