# How to stop a GIF from animating after a certain amount of time (on a web page)?

Tags: html, animation, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

When I have a page open with an animated GIF in it, and the tab is active in the window, it uses up CPU.

I'm wondering if there's a way to mark up the HTML so that a GIF will play for a specified amount of time or number of loops.

Or perhaps I am best served by using a static image and setting its source to the GIF on hover (which I believe most mobile browsers patch by allowing hover to be set on tap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe HTML or the DOM provides any control over GIF animation, but you can exercise a limited amount of control from your image generation tool over the number of loops.

For example, in Photoshop:

[image]

IE9 and Chrome respect the loop count; I imagine that all browsers do, though I can't find a mention in the spec for how looping is supposed to behave.

[GIF89a Spec](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/GIF/spec-gif89a.txt)

If you can't modify the images, or want to stop them at different times, perhaps just replace the animated GIF with a static GIF using a bit of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I use Fireworks to make animated gifs and from within fireworks you can adjust those settings without having to do anything to the html.

Comment: Does a gif allow you to specify a certain number of loops before it stops? And will browsers generally follow that setting? Sure would beat the hell out of that really scary hackery being done with the `<canvas>` in the other link posted.

Comment: yes. I don't know what other software will do this for you, but I do it all the time with Fireworks. (if you like this answer, upvote it! Thanks!)