# Draw a Play button on canvas in javascript - triangle in a circle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, greasemonkey

So I'm creating a simple userscript for me - I want to draw a play button over shaded version of any GIF image on the site to have them only played when I want to.

I have inspired myself [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276742/607407). To make the whole thing nice, I'm drawing a green circle over the animation. This is my intended effect (I really wonder if once can make some shapes in GIMP):

[image: paused animation (created in gimp)]

And this is what I currently have:

[image: paused cleese]

<sup>The Cleese ironic face animation comes from this [GIF portal](http://replygif.net/746)</sup>

I made a fiddle of my current [GIF pauser userscript](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/KNAGK/1/).

The critical code for printing the circle:

```
//Assume these variables
var ctx = canvas context (2d)
var w = canvas width
var h = canvas height
//The code:
ctx.beginPath();
//I'm making sure the circle will always fit - therefore Math.min
ctx.arc(w/2, h/2, Math.min(60, w/2-20, h/2-20), 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,180,0,0.5)';
ctx.fill();
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

I hope it's clear that the triangle must always fit into the circle (size of which may vary). It must have the vertical line a little bit shorter then the other two, which must be of equal length.

I'm totally not interested in any existing GIF pausing libraries. Keep in mind that the question is about the triangle, not the GIFs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/32ECU/

```
//Draw a triangle in it
ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(w/3, h/3);
ctx.lineTo(w/3, h-h/3);
ctx.lineTo(w-w/4, h/2);
ctx.lineTo(w/3, h/3);
ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
ctx.fill();
```