# Displaying gif URL as image only

Tags: javascript, jquery, gif, summernote

Is there any simple way to display **GIF** as image only on webpage.
Let say user has posted

http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/04/Dvdp3.gif

which is a gif but when displaying I don't want to show gif. Actually, I am using summernote.

Comment: No. Not possible... Path will be confusion....

Comment: Keep in mind that JPEG and PNG doesn't support animations (although APNG does, but it's natively supported by Firefox only), and JPEG doesn't support transparency. Is that ok with you?

Comment: @MaxArt I just don't want to show animations in GIF. Is it possible to show it as a image only ?

Comment: @C-linkNepal I don't think I deserve a downvote here; my perception :)

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is that you also upload the images that they send by URL and convert them.

Comment: I believe you were down voted as it is hard to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: @C-linkNepal It is not impossible :)

Comment: Your updated question is good, but previously you were asking to change extension from gif to jpg and to which I was said not possible....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your browser supports `<canvas>`, you can take advantage of it to display frozen gifs:

```
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("imageCanvas"),
    image = new Image();

image.src = "/path/to/image.gif";
image.addEventListener("load", function() {
    canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);
});
```

**[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/raxag/1/edit)** (activate the Javascript panel, and disable the CSS panel).

Tested in IE9-11, Chrome and Firefox.

**Update**

Using the technique above, there's something more you can do if you actually want an `<img>` element and not a `<canvas>`:

```
var preloadImage = new Image(),
    finalImage = new Image(),
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

preloadImage.src = "/path/to/image.gif";
preloadImage.addEventListener("load", function() {
    canvas.width = preloadImage.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = preloadImage.naturalHeight;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    finalImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    // Append to the DOM. Choose the parent you want.
    document.body.appendChild(finalImage);
});
```

Notice that the canvas isn't even appended to the document, just like `preloadImage`.

This works only if:

- the image's source satisfies the same origin policy or
- the server allows cross-origin requests, and the image is loaded with `crossOrigin` enabled (`preloadImage.crossOrigin = "anonymous";`).

Otherwise the canvas is "tainted" and `toDataURL` throws a `SecurityError`.

Answer (score 0):

GIF is a very different format as JPEG format.
When a user is posting it, you will have to convert it to the desired format risking to lose transparency and such.
Displaying a gif as another format as is is not possible.

Or just let is display as a GIF, why do you want to change that?

Comment: @randomizer The site I am developing is not expecting to have any gif. I can convert gif to simple image when user is uploading image. But I am not able to do it for URL's.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question.

Do you want to display this gif with an url that does not end with .gif ?

If yes, you can tweak the mimetype in the headers.

The browser don't care about the extension displayed in URL. It just care about MIME type wich describe what to do with the data. A html page sent with 'text/plain' MIME type will display the sourcecode like if it was a txt, it won't be interpreted as html.
You can rename you gif as .jpeg and send it to browser with 'image/gif' mimetype.

If you are using apache you can change MIME type with .htaccess. Add a text file called .htaccess in the folder of your image with this text in it :

`AddType image/gif yourfilename`

This should work if your host allow it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop all gifs from animating you can use [the freezeAllGifs() function posted by Makaze in this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24707088/262618). You should execute it after the page loaded, which should stop all animated gifs.

It might not be a great solution, but the only other one I can think of is a server-side script that would download all posted gifs, conver tthem and then replace the original links with urls of the converted files on the local server.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this inefficient solution, but it works!

```
setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#img1').attr('src',$('#img1').attr('src'))
    },1)
}, 2000)
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/MEaWP/2/

Comment: This is terrible in many ways, it may work (after 2 seconds...) but please don't use this.

Comment: Yes, it is, Canvas is the best solution