# Is it possible to control playback of animated webP images?

Tags: javascript, html, image, webp

Does webP have a javascript API?

I want to seek to a specific point in an animated webP. I haven't come across any documentation to suggest it does but no harm asking SO.

**Note**: I'm not interested in the HTML5 video element, webM or other video formats.

Comment: Did you get any solution of your question?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Answer (score 2):

As of 2024 there is an experimental support in chromium based browsers for [ImageDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageDecoder) which does provide an API to extract individual particular frames which can be eventually used to mimic control of  the playback.

Answer (score -1):

## Abstract

> Does webP have a JavaScript API?

It seems to me that webP is not supported as an `API`. But you could control them on the backend and on the frontend.

The last, the one that I understand, is able to be manipulated not very efficiently but being simplified!

For example?

## ✓Pausing an animation

<sub>(however I wouldn't recommend doing [such a thing, exampled here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)):</sub>

```
[].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_webp_image).map(pause_webp);

const is_webp_image=(i)=> {
    return /^(?!data:).*\.webp/i.test(i.src);
}

const pause_webp=(i)=> {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var w = c.width = i.width;
    var h = c.height = i.height;
    c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
    try {
        i.src = c.toDataURL("image/webp"); // if possible, retain all css aspects
    } catch(e) { // cross-domain -- mimic original with all its tag attributes
        for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
            c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
        i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
    }
}
```

That was pausing respectively a webp or gif.

## ✓Controlling playback:

To control playback, I recommend to slice the webp on the *backend* like this pseudocode; **given** a webp file variable and some self-made or adopted backend API there (see that it is just an example of this):

```
// pseudocode on backend:
    var li=[];
    for(var itr=0;itr<len(webp)/*how long*/ ;itr++){
     list.push( giveWebURI (webp.slice(itr,len(webp)))); 
//                ^  e.g http://example.org/versions/75-sec-until-end.webp# 
    };
```

Then on the frontend JS:

```
    const playFrom=(time)=>{
    document.querySelector(/*selector*/).src=`
http://example.org/versions/${time}-sec-until-end.webp
     `;
     };
```

I would call this but an introduction into backend/frontend/file interactions.