# GIF will only play once when I press the button

Tags: javascript, gif

So, I have a button that plays a coinflip animation. The problem is if I push the button and get a result I got before, it wont play the GIF again. (Gifs are only meant to run once per button press).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
<p id="flipDisplay"></p>
<button onclick="display()">Flip the Coin!</button>
<script>
  function coinFlip() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
  }
  function display() {
    if (coinFlip()) {      
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "./tflip.gif";    
      showImage(img);

    } else {      
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "./ctflip.gif";
      showImage(img);
    }
  }

  function showImage(img){
      var display = document.getElementById("flipDisplay");
      display.innerHTML = '';
      display.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, its pronounced Gif not Gif.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's pronounced Gif.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)