# Is it possible to embed an animated gif into html as a static image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gif

So, the idea is simple: I've got a large number of GIFs and I have to create a gallery. I'd like to use FancyBox (probably this question won't be different if I used Lightbox or any other modal) which works nicely in terms of the modal itself, but I'd like thumbnails to be static, not animated. I wonder if there's some nice trick to insert those gifs as static images.

Note: in fact, I have to create a large number of small galleries, so it's not big deal that those GIFs are slower to load than separately generated static images.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

Comment: @raina77ow thanks, have to test that one. Not sure if I'll be able to stop animation quickly enough

Comment: What if you just won't show the GIFs till processed that way?

Comment: @raina77ow that will complicate the solution but that's an option, thanks