# How to load gif image with time limit in php

Tags: javascript, limit, gif

On the website that I am developing there is a gif. Gif is loaded when moving from one page to another, the code is like this

```
<div class="loader-wrap">
        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/matoa-preloader.gif'); ?>">
      </div>
```

i use javascript to limit the time like this

```
//untuk loading page
        $(function() {
            $(".loader-wrap").fadeOut(2000, function() {
                $(".content").fadeIn(1000);        
            });
        });​
```

the gif is to long, how can i limit to play the gif just for 2 second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in PHP. This is a front-end issue, not a backend issue. You can use this [link](https://ezgif.com/cut) to cut down the duration of the gif and replace the old gif.