# I'm having an issue where the 'mouseover' event is simply starting before I even mouseover the selected element

Tags: javascript, gif, mouseover

As soon as I load or reload the page. The gif i've included in the html starts playing.

```
$('.text').mouseover(function() {
$('.hover').css("visibility", "visible"); })

$('.text').mouseout(function() {
$('.hover').css("visibility", "hidden"); });
```

I want the gif to start whenever I hover over the relevant element and stop when I take my cursor off. This JS is in a script tag within the body of HTML doc. It works after I hover over the 'text' element for the first time. Would love some guidance on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the visibility of the element when the page loads (i.e. before you hover for the first time)? Perhaps it's set to `visibility: visible` on load?

Comment: Please include more of your HTML, specifically the markup for `.text` and `.hover`. Do you have more elements with those classes on the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

Comment: you could convert your gif to a sprite and manually animate with css and pause/play with js. or use a library Supergif or do it manually using a canvas.

Comment: @Cully that sounds like what the issue could be. I'm unsure on how to set the visibility state on the img element upon loading.

Comment: I'll post the suggestion as an answer.

Comment: @Salief Did that work?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the visibility of the image is `visible` on the initial page load. When you do your first mouseover, then mouseout, it gets set to `hidden`, which is your expected behavior. Try setting the visibility of the img to `hidden`, by one of these methods:

1. Add a style in the head of the page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      img.hover { visibility: hidden; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <img src='path/to/image.gif' class='hover' />
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Or, set the style inline in the image itself:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <img src='path/to/image.gif' class='hover' style='visibility: hidden' />
  </body>
</html>
```