# Disable gif animation programmatically

Tags: image, animation, gif

Hi i have a gif whose animation i want to disable programmatically in a web page .I do not want to replace the gif with equivalent image.The gif must be same when "saved as" .And i want to be able to do that for selected gifs only not all gifs

Comment: Why? Sometimes it's good to work out 'why', take a step back, and solve the real problem.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953766/disabling-gif-animation-in-html

Comment: @joe :this only is the real problem , just disabling animation and let users to download view the animation after downloading ;) sounds nerdy but thats the actual requirement

Comment: @belisarius : yeah using html,javascript or php

Comment: @Justin Morgan : i coudn't find the answer to my problem on that page

Comment: @Mukesh the answer in that page is "you can't"

Comment: @Mukesh Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically/4276742#4276742

Answer (score 1):

You could create a thumbnail that is just the first frame (non-animated), then put a download link next to it to download the animated version.  Any solution is going to be a workaround though; you can't tell the web browser to not animate animated GIFs.